# Dummy variables using pd.get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sklearn-pandas, dummy-variable

I have many columns for which I want to create a dummy variable to use it in a logistic regression later. I use:

```
rdd=rd['cuser'] #rd is the original data frame
cat_vars=['income','marital','edu','race','age','gender','sexuality','SPD']
for var in cat_vars:
    temp = pd.get_dummies(rd[var],prefix=var)
    rdd=pd.concat([rdd,temp],axis=1)
rdd.columns.values
```

I get the output as:

```
array(['cuser', 'income_20-49K', 'income_50-74K', 'income_< 20K',
       'income_> 75K', 'marital_Married', 'marital_Never Married',
       'marital_Separated/Divorced/Widowed', 'edu_< High school',
       'edu_College graduate', 'edu_High school graduate',
       'edu_Some college', 'race_Black', 'race_Hispanics', 'race_Other',
       'race_White', 'age_15-17', 'age_18-21', 'age_>=22',
       'gender_Female', 'gender_Male', 'sexuality_Bisexual',
       'sexuality_Hetrosexuals', 'sexuality_Lesbian or gay',
       'sexuality_Other', 'SPD_No SPD', 'SPD_Past-month SPD',
       'SPD_Past-year SPD'], dtype=object)
```

I then want to estimate a logistic regression for which I create my x and y variables as:

```
X=rdd.loc[:,rdd.columns!='cuser']
y=rdd.loc[:,rdd.columns=='cuser']
lr_model = LogisticRegression()
lr_model.fit(X_, y_,sample_weight=wt)
```

The issue is the created dummy variables are for all the values of the categorical variable. Hence, my created X includes includes even the reference category. For example for income dummies 'income_20-49K', 'income_50-74K', 'income_< 20K','income_> 75K' one of these should be the reference and hence not in the regression and X. Is there a way to do this such that I do not have to specify the reference category for each variable in my code:

```
X=rdd.loc[:,rdd.columns!='cuser']
```

Thanks for your input!

Comment: I am confused with what you are trying to do. Do you want to do one hot encoding for all your features? One hot encoding is used for classification.

Comment: I did a quick search to familiarize myself with hot encoding which if I understand correctly is a way to convert a categorical variable to dummies. I am simply trying to create dummies for each categorical variable and then create a data frame X that I can then pass on as my dependent variables in the logistic regression. When I create the dummy variables as in my code, say for income which has four categories, I get four dummy variables, however in my regression, I will only include 3 of the dummies and drop one as the reference category. I am wondering what is a good way to do.

Comment: I am not sure what the reference category is or why you would want to drop one because you will use all the data for that feature label.

Comment: I see, I guess my approach is more manual. Usually, when using dummies variables, theoretically you will create n-1 dummies for a variable when it has n categories. For example for each day of week which are 7 you will only include 6 dummies one for each 6 days and the one you leave out is the reference day against which we measure all the other estimated coefficients. 
Thanks. I am looking into hot encoding now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['variable_name'], drop_first=True)
df= pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)

This will avoid the dummy variable trap in a logistic regression model